# Azure Python Function App deployment fails on adding tensorflow to requirements.txt

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a Python Function App created with Consumption Plan. I am trying to deploy an app that makes use `tensorflow` using the VS Code Function App extension. But the `Deploy to Function App` fails on just adding `tensorflow` to requirements.txt. I get the following error:

```
collecting tensorflow
6:04:44 am PostComparisonApp: [00:34:44+0000]   Downloading tensorflow-2.10.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (578.1 MB)
6:05:10 am PostComparisonApp: Done in 27 sec(s).
6:05:14 am PostComparisonApp: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
6:05:14 am PostComparisonApp: Generating summary of Oryx build
6:05:14 am PostComparisonApp: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
6:05:14 am PostComparisonApp: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
6:05:14 am PostComparisonApp: Deployment Failed. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
6:05:26 am PostComparisonApp: Deployment failed.
```

I get this error on no other change to the templace function that is provided on creating function in the extension.
I have also tried running the `func azure functionapp publish` command as well, but get the same error. I have tried deleting the App and creating new one, but still same error.

Comment: Hi, you're not alone -- I am also experiencing this problem. The deployment fails until I remove tensorflow from requirements.txt, and it seems to be the only thing causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- This is the way I was able to deploy tensor flow with the azure function.
- First inside the folder I create a virtual environment using command

```
python -m venev test
```

- Then I installed tensorflow using

```
pip isntall tensorflow
```

- Now I created the function inside the folder and added `tensorflow` to requirment.txt.
- the function just return the version of the tensorflow

function code :

```
import  logging
import tensorflow as  tf
import azure.functions as  func

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
name = tf.__version__
return  func.HttpResponse(name)
```

- Then I just deployed the function to azure

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of different things, I found that if you use `tensorflow-cpu` instead of `tensorflow` in requirements.txt, it deploys just fine.